# "Is not a function" error message at string modification with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to modify the value of a string given a condition in a ternary operator statement:

```
($.trim($("#la").val())) ? a = $("#la").val() : a = 'NaN'
```

However I'm getting the error message:

> > `"NaN" is not a function`

What have I got wrong?

Comment: Code read-ability is important, assigned the trimmed val to a variable and use that. This hurts to read.

Comment: could you post a fiddle? what does `#la` contain? how do you use `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd generally do that like this

```
var a = $.trim($("#la").val()).length ? $("#la").val() : NaN;
```

or in this case, where an empty string would be falsy, you could do

```
var a = $('#a').val() || NaN;
```

The issue with `NaN` not being a function is probably because you quoted it, so it's a string, but unquoting it wont make it a function, it's still a native property!

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = ($.trim($('#la').val()).length > 0) ? $('#la').val() : 'NaN';
```

should give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var value = $("#la").val(); 
var a = ($.trim(value).length>0) ? value : 'NaN';
```